# slumber returns empty string instead of object data

Tags: django, tastypie

I've built an API for my Django app using Tastypie and it works OK when I send data using commandline curl. But when I try to use slumber like this:

```
api = slumber.API('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/', auth=('username','pass'))
new = api.resource.post({'field':'value'})
```

the object is created OK in the database, but **new** is just '' instead of a dictionary containing at least the id of newly created object.

What can be wrong? Please, provide some tips how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in slumber, use version 0.4.2